# Why is App Insights only showing Warning and Error tracing levels? What about lower levels?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a .Net Framework 4.5.1 app service that has the following code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(" Console.WriteLine");
Trace.WriteLine(" Trace.WriteLine");
Trace.TraceInformation(" Trace.TraceInformation");
Trace.TraceWarning(" Trace.TraceWarning");
Trace.TraceError(" Trace.TraceError");
```

I would like to be able to see logs that we log into Azure when the app is in production. So I enabled Application Service Logging for my web app:

[image]

As you can see, I have the logging level set to **verbose** because we want to see everything. I also have Application Insights turned on for my app. But when I check the logs, all I see are the logs at the warning level and higher.

I checked in the "logs" tab:

[image]

I also checked in my blob storage. I see logs, but they're all on a **warning** level or higher.

There was one way I got this to work, and that's using the feature that saves logs to a file system. But that feature turns itself off after 12 hours, and the file might get too big anyways, and I'd like to use Azure Insights since it has a nicer interface.

How can I view all my logs my application outputs over a long period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have various trace levels in your web app but are only interested in having certain levels of logs sent to the logging endpoint, you can set a filter for the minimum level in your application settings under Configuration. By default, even without the app setting, the minimum trace level is set to **Warning**.

### How to set App setting for AppServiceAppLogs level

The application setting name will be `APPSERVICEAPPLOGS_TRACE_LEVEL` and the value will be the minimum level (ie. Error, Warning, Verbose, etc.). Refer to [TraceLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelevel?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.

[image]

#### Links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/31/AzMon-AppServiceAppLogs.html (Image Source)

Comment: Thanks. I do have it turned on. What is off in the picture is logging the logging to a *file*. Because that only works for 12 hours. If you look under that setting in my screenshot, I do have it turned on for storing logs in a blob.

Comment: In that case, please ensure your app service has the `APPSERVICEAPPLOGS_TRACE_LEVEL` set to verbose https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/31/AzMon-AppServiceAppLogs.html

Comment: Would adding this config work on ASP.NET core? I have a .NET 6 application and I want to set the logging to Verbose.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just remove all logging configuration from config files like `appsettings.json` and use the `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` type specifier in `Startup.cs`, like so:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(conf =>
    {
        conf.AddApplicationInsights();

        conf.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information);
        conf.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
        conf.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("System", LogLevel.Warning);
    });

    ...
}
```

It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-code).